# How to communicate informational message value from different components to parent component and display it all at a time in angular 8

Tags: angular

There are four components in an angular application and each component is having some informational message. I want to communicate those messages from each component to parent component. How I can do this?

Comment: Can you add a working example or some code to exactly describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The most scalable solution is to create a service and inject into your parent component and all the children components.  Your child components can add messages to the service, and the parent can access them.

You could also use `@Output` event emitters from the components, but I don't really recommend that approach unless its for a very simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `@Output` and `EventEmitter`

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class ChildComponent  {
@Output() message: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
}
```

Now inside any of your method/based on your logic in your child.component.ts, do

```
someMethod() {
this.message.emit('Hello');
}
```

Now, inside your parent component html,

`<app-child (message)="onMessageReceived($event)"> </app-child>`

and finally, inside parent ts,

```
onMessageReceived(message) {
console.log(message);
}
```

If your still facing issues, check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-output)

> Similarly, you can do the same thing by emitting messages for all your
> 4 children components and listening to the events in your parent
> component

> Also, if your use case is not as simple as the one I showed above, you
> can create a shared service and Inject in your components, update them
> in child component and access them in Parent component.